# NetSuite: SuiteApp to Group Tasks?

Tags: netsuite

is there a SuiteApp which would allow to group tasks?
Example: Employee Onboarding
And you could have multiple tasks under the template assigned to different people etc.

Thanks

I can't see any suiteapp that would do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with custom records & workflow, you can try to do this, I am using project name for the custom records for illustration :-

1. Create a custom record name "Project Header", with field say Project Name. You can create more fields like project status or project type if required.

Create a Subtab "Project Tasks" and Assign to the Child Records after the below custom record is created.

2. Create another custom record "Project Tasks" which will be child of the "Project Header" with below fields :-
   Project Id > Type:List/Record, List/Record: Task Header, Record Is Parent: Checked
   Task Name > Type:free-form text
   Assigned To > Type:List/Record, List/Record: Employee

Turn On "Allow Child Record Editing" and "Allow Delete" in this custom record.

3. Then try to enter a new project with more than 1 tasks and save. Assuming this is your project template. You can edit and make copy to "duplicate" the project.
4. You can further enhanced this by using workflow to send email alerts upon new tasks created to the assignee.

Hope this give you some ideas if you thinking to customise this yourselves which will give you more flexibility then suiteapp.